# MDX Group Dimensions y new Dimension

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube, dimensional-modeling

I'm brand new in Cube world and I need to do a query extending some values form dimensions.
For example:
Having dimension [time].[Numeric Month], with values [time].[Numeric Month].&[1]..[time].[Numeric Month].&[12]

What i need is group that values like this

```
[time].[Numeric Month].&[1]...[time].[Numeric Month].&[4] = A
[time].[Numeric Month].&[5]...[time].[Numeric Month].&[12] = B
```

(is an example)

and perform a query wich result show be like this on Rows

```
A
|->1
|->2
|->3
|->4
B
|->5
|->6
|->7
|->8
|->9
|->10
|->11
|->12
```

I could do the grouping but when I tried to use the same hierarchy used for the grouping as another level of row I've an error(it make sense) of hierarchy is used more than once

It's possible to do this kind of query?

This is the MDX:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Tiempo].[Mes Numerico].[A] AS 
    [Tiempo].[Mes Numerico].&[1] 
  MEMBER [Tiempo].[Mes Numerico].[A         ] AS 
    Aggregate
    (
      {
        [Tiempo].[Mes Numerico].&[1]
       ,[Tiempo].[Mes Numerico].&[2]
       ,[Tiempo].[Mes Numerico].&[3]
      }
    ) 
  MEMBER [Tiempo].[Mes Numerico].[D         ] AS 
    Aggregate
    (
      {
        [Tiempo].[Mes Numerico].&[10]
       ,[Tiempo].[Mes Numerico].&[11]
       ,[Tiempo].[Mes Numerico].&[12]
      }
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Proyectos Tiempos-Horas40538889] AS 
    [Measures].[Proyectos Tiempos-Horas] 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    (
      [Tiempo].[Mes Numerico]
     ,
        {
          [Tiempo].[Mes Numerico].[A         ]
         ,[Tiempo].[Mes Numerico].[D         ]
        }
      * 
        {[Measures].[Proyectos Tiempos-Horas40538889]}
    ) ON COLUMNS
FROM [VisionarisDW];
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this should work:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Tiempo].[Mes Numerico].[A] AS 

     AGGREGATE
     ( 
          {
            [Tiempo].[Mes Numerico].&[1]
           ,[Tiempo].[Mes Numerico].&[2]
           ,[Tiempo].[Mes Numerico].&[3]
          }
          , [Measures].[Proyectos Tiempos-Horas]
     )

  MEMBER [Tiempo].[Mes Numerico].[B] AS 

     AGGREGATE
     (   
          {
            [Tiempo].[Mes Numerico].&[4]
           ,[Tiempo].[Mes Numerico].&[5]
           ,[Tiempo].[Mes Numerico].&[6]
          }
          , [Measures].[Proyectos Tiempos-Horas]
      )

  MEMBER [Measures].[Proyectos Tiempos-Horas40538889] AS 
    [Measures].[Proyectos Tiempos-Horas] 

SELECT 

  NON EMPTY [Measures].[Proyectos Tiempos-Horas40538889] ON COLUMNS,

  {
      [Tiempo].[Mes Numerico].&[1],
      [Tiempo].[Mes Numerico].&[2],
      [Tiempo].[Mes Numerico].&[3],
      [Tiempo].[Mes Numerico].[A],
      [Tiempo].[Mes Numerico].&[4],
      [Tiempo].[Mes Numerico].&[5],
      [Tiempo].[Mes Numerico].&[6],
      [Tiempo].[Mes Numerico].[B]
  } ON ROWS

FROM [VisionarisDW];
```